# Loop through all UserForms then each control to get Top, Left, etc

Tags: excel, loops, collections, userform

I have about 10 userforms.  Each is named ChoiceForm with a letter suffix (ChoiceFormA, ChoiceFormB, etc.).  I would like to design a sub that will output the properties of each control & the UF itself to a sheet.  All I need is to determine how to loop through the UFs in the first place.

The following code seems like it should work, but when it hits the For Each loop, it simply ignores it due to no members being in the VBA.Userforms collection (I assume). One thing I have considered is that I can't do this outside of a UF module, which I hope is not the case.

Thanks.

```
Sub UserFormStatistics()

    Dim ufForm As Object
    Dim ufCol As Collection
    
    Set ufCol = New Collection

    For Each ufForm In VBA.UserForms
    
        ufCol.Add (ufForm)
        
    Next

...

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to loop through each form and then every control within that form ...

```
Public Sub GetUserFormControls()
    Dim objVBComponent As Object, objForm As UserForm, objCtrl As Control
    
    For Each objVBComponent In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        If objVBComponent.Type = vbext_ct_MSForm Then
            Debug.Print objVBComponent.Name
            
            Set objForm = objVBComponent.Designer
            
            For Each objCtrl In objForm.Controls
                Debug.Print "... " & objCtrl.Name
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

... to make this work though, you need to add a reference to **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility** ...

[image: Extensibility]

... and also ensure that you've set it to trust access to the VBA project ...

[image: Trust Centre]

You should be able to adapt it as need be to your project.